# How to convert a captured Image or image selected from gallary to base64?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

User can capture or select a image from gallery. I would like to upload that image to server.

This is my code for camera -

```
camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    //String encode = ImageBase64.encode(i);
                    startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                }
            });
```

And this is my code to select a image from gallery -

```
gallary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent g = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(g, GALLARY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

Also, I am displaying that image with below code -

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                uploaded_img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
        if(requestCode == GALLARY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            uploaded_img.setImageURI(uri);
        }
    }
```

Now, I would like to convert this image to base64 and upload to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public static String convertToBase64(String path) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }


    public static Bitmap decodeFromBase64ToBitmap(String encodedImage) {

        byte[] decodedString = android.util.Base64.decode(encodedImage, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        return decodedByte;
    }
```

I've made it static in my project, so i don't have to create class instance.